# Is it possible to forbid download from libraries to some users?

Tags: library, download, authorization

I have a customer that asked me if is possible to limit authorization to a single library for some users. 
He wants them to just read the files in the library but to forbid downloading them.
I couldn't find any option for that.

Comment: "Read" as in "View the contents of the file"? What kind of files is the customer storing in that library?

Comment: Docx, xlsx and pdf.
and Yes, "read" as "view the contents".

Comment: doesn't 'view only' permission prevent downloads?

Comment: If only it were so simple... I would not have asked.

Answer (score 6):

Out of the box, this isn’t possible. You can, however, restrict both download and printing with Information Rights Management for all users, but not for a group of users. And since there is a snipping tool and a print screen function on all operating systems, users can with a little effort still get the content of document and save it somewhere else. So this doesn’t make your document content protected, just less vulnerable.

Sources:

- [Apply Information Rights Management to a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-Information-Rights-Management-to-a-list-or-library-3bdb5c4e-94fc-4741-b02f-4e7cc3c54aa1)
- [Restrict download and printing document from SharePoint document library](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75089e9c-bff2-4b83-9edb-c5b21e384b5c/restrict-download-and-printing-document-from-sharepoint-document-library?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: +1 , adding msdn link , may help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms458245.aspx

Comment: I'll Try the proposed solutions this 'noon. =D thx

Comment: Often, such requirements are not about technically making it impossible, but about making sure that users understand that such downloading and storing is, by policy, deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do that even if you disable the "Download a copy" button. If a customer can open files in a client application like Word or any kind of PDF viewer, that user will be able to save the files from there.