# Site/Library Offline Client Availabily setting = No does not restrict download, Why?

Tags: sharepoint-online, download

SharePoint Online

We find that setting Offline Client Availability
to "No" in a document library or site does not restrict users from downloading documents. I am unable to determine the reason/s this setting would not function as expected? Can someone assist in resolving the issue.

Thank you,
George

Answer (score 1):

I think that this setting is not well explained in Microsoft documentation, [here the article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Prevent-users-from-downloading-content-from-a-site-e17bf52b-fa5d-41cf-9eb0-d3812542424e). I think that is not a matter of letting users download those documents but avoid them to work offline. As the article try to explain, setting "Offline Client Availability" to "No" makes users to not work offline with these documents so they cannot use the OneDrive sync process to update SharePoint libraries. This is the only explanation that makes sense to me.

Comment: I appreciate this remark. Changing Offline Client Availability to "No" does remove "Sync" from library command options. It does nothing to the "Download" option, which is visible on the command bar either Offline Client Availability: Yes/No.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. "Download" option is always available but "Sync" depends on "Offline Client Availability".

Answer (score 0):

From the Q+A on the web this seems a common topic for inquiry. It was not clear from experimenting with settings, but I think I understand now that it is not possible to restrict download while permitting document creation and editing using SharePoint library permissions and the Client Availability setting, even if you can hide the Download command from the interface. Save As / Print functionality of browser and online / offline apps permit "offline-ing" documents. One may use Information Rights Management to impose restriction on document content. Even with IRM the select-all-copy-past scenario cannot be excluded. It was helpful to read the response to this question, [Is it possible to forbid download from libraries to some users?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167548/is-it-possible-to-forbid-download-from-libraries-to-some-users). Thank you.